# Splitting $2\times2$ or $3\times3$ matrix into two matrices under boundary conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, interpolation

I have a $2\times2$ or $3\times3$ transformation matrix $T$, which is the product of two transformations $T=AB$. (e.g. affine transformations). The elements of $A$ can be implemented as floating point numbers, where the elements of $B$ are fixed point with a given finite range (say $-10, \dots, +10$) and the elements of $B$ shall utilize that range as much as possible.

My idea was to introduce a control variable $\gamma$, which I can optimize to get the best balance between the fixed- and the floating point part:
\begin{align} 
A' &= f(\gamma, A, B) \\
B' &= g(\gamma, A, B) 
\end{align}
with
\begin{align} 
f(0, A, B) &= AB \\
f(1, A, B) &= 1 \\
g(0, A, B) &= 1 \\
g(1, A, B) &= AB 
\end{align}
and
$$
T = f(\gamma, A, B) \cdot g(\gamma, A, B) = AB\ \forall\ \gamma \in [0,1]
$$

But how can I find the functions $f$ and $g$ which fulfill the above boundary conditions?

Comment: When you write $f(1, A, B) = 1$, what kind of object is $1$? The number $1$? The identity matrix of the same size as $AB$?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we can interpret $1$ as the identity matrix $I$ of appropriate size, linear interpolation should work:
$$
f(\gamma, A, B) = (1 - \gamma) AB + \gamma I. 
$$
This has the property that $f(0, A, B) = AB$ and $f(1, A, B) = I$.

In fact, any parametrized path from $(x, y) = (1, 0)$ to $(x, y) = (0, 1)$ will do. This is the linear path
$$
(x, y) = (1 - \gamma, \gamma), 
\quad 0 \leq \gamma \leq 1.
$$

Can you write down the linear interpolation for $g$?

> We can just parametrize in reverse: $g(\gamma) = f(1 - \gamma)$ or explicitly, $$ g(\gamma, A, B) = (1 - \gamma) I + \gamma AB. $$

Comment: Note: I have not addressed any of the information about data types.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was in one point not clear: $T=f(\gamma, A,B)*g(\gamma, A,B)=AB$ must hold for all $\gamma$ between 0 and 1. I also updated the question.